# Problems passing data between different classes with a method

Tags: cocoa-touch, parameter-passing

I have this in a class:

```
    NSString *globalMidiData = @"30a0a00\n";

    switch (IndicatorCheckNXT) {
        case 1:
            [testRobot checkTestRobot:globalMidiData];
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
```

And in another class I have this:

```
-(void) checkTestRobot: (NSString *)midiDataGlobal{
    bool pressed;
    bool pressed2;
    NSString *miawmiaw =[NSString alloc];
    miawmiaw=midiDataGlobal;
}
```

And I got this message:

-[AppDelegate checkTestRobot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18acb0
2012-11-23 20:45:31.755 Exemple1[477:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate checkTestRobot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18acb0'

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's your definition of `testRobot` and how is it assigned an object?  (Also, no need to `alloc` a string if you're just going to assign a different one to the same variable.)

Comment: I trust you realize that your response provided no information that would help anyone diagnose your problem.  You're giving the impression that, having asked your vague question, you'd rather not get involved with finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you send `checkTestRobot` to the wrong object. `testRobot` seems to point to the AppDelegate and not to an instance of your class.

Also you should replace this:

```
NSString *miawmiaw =[NSString alloc];
miawmiaw=midiDataGlobal;
```

with:

```
NSString *miawmiaw = [midiDataGlobal copy];
```

Comment: The switch is in the AppleDelegate. TestRobot is in the view where I have checkTestRobot. How I do it?